# the object of type A cannot be converted to type B

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a programme with which I want to start Windows services. I search all services for a name (for example "VMware") and write them in a list. Now I want to start a service. I then get the error message "The object of type "WpfApp1.myService" cannot be converted to type "System.Data.DataRowView"."

When I start all services it works.
Here is my code (XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
    
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"RowBackground="#fff" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#525252"ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Height="390" MaxHeight="390"AlternatingRowBackground="#f2f2f2" BorderBrush="#000" BorderThickness="1"ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path='ProductId'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Path='Product'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Path='Category'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path='Price'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="start">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="btnStart" Content="start" Click="btnStrt_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="start all services" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here the CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;



namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                ObservableCollection<myService> items = new ObservableCollection<myService>();

                ServiceController[] scServices;
                scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();


                string meineServices = "VMware";

                foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
                {
                    if (scTemp.DisplayName.Contains(meineServices))
                    {
                        items.Add(new myService() { ProductId = "1", Product = scTemp.ServiceName, Category = scTemp.DisplayName, Price = scTemp.Status.ToString() });
                    }
                }
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnStrt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;
                ObservableCollection<myService> items = new ObservableCollection<myService>();

                ServiceController[] scServices;
                scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();


                string meineServices = dataRowView[1].ToString();

                foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
                {
                    if (scTemp.DisplayName.Equals(meineServices))
                    {
                        scTemp.Start();
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Dienst gestartet");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ObservableCollection<myService> items = new ObservableCollection<myService>();

                ServiceController[] scServices;
                scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();


                string meineServices = "VMware";

                foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
                {
                    if (scTemp.DisplayName.Contains(meineServices))
                    {
                        scTemp.Start();
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
    public class myService
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The DataContext is the data item (myService). DataRowView is the container the data item is wrapped into in order to render it as child of the DataGrid. You don't need the DataRowView in your context. You already have full access to the items source of the DataGid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
<Button Name="btnStart" Content="Starten" CommandParameter="{Binding Path='Dienstname'}" Click="btnStarten_Click" />
```

and in the CS:

```
object Row_Anzeigename = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
string meineServices = Row_Anzeigename.ToString();
```

Thank you for pushing me in the right direction.